# Dual monitors show white background and mouse pointer with X shape

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors

I have a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04 on my Lenovo Thinkpad T61. My graphics card is an NVIDIA Corporation G86 (Quadro NVS 140M).

I have installed an additional driver for NVIDIA. When I go to NVIDIA's X server settings interface → X server Display Configuration, I can detect my other monitor (BenQ FP222W) but neither or TwinView or X separate are working fine.

It shows a white background and my mouse pointer with a big "X" shape.

In Ubuntu 11.10 It was working fine.

I clicked "save to X configuration file", logged out, restarted the graphical service (LightDM) . I also restarted the computer, but it did not help.

I even enabled not the recommended version of nvidia driver,no success.

What you fellows think?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.